# Does Selenium/Protractor look for element in current loaded page?

Tags: selenium, protractor

Does Selenium/Protractor look for element in current loaded page, or look in the entire application when using the same Css Selector for same elements?

Eg:

Save Button on Customers Form `class="save"`

Save Button on Vendors Form `class="save"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protractor works by interacting with the browser (via selenium).  Selenium uses browser drivers to interact with your page, and the browser only contains the code that it asked for (returned from the server, based on the type of request that was made).

So **yes,** **it only looks for elements in the currently loaded page**.  It has no access to your entire application code.

Comment: Thank you so much Gunderson

Answer (score 0):

Selenium looks for the element only on the loaded page. Not sure about Protractor though.

Comment: I was doing some experiments, like count of this objects, and apparently you are right.